# marklogic data load on local mlcp

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

```
c:\windows\system32>"C:\Users\as\epmp test\mlcp-8.0.6-bin\mlcp-8.0.6\bin\m
lcp.bat" -options_file "C:\Users\as\epmp test\ML Training\training-session
s\training-1-local-marklogic-setup\training-project-data-import.options"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
17/05/04 15:23:10 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
17/05/04 15:23:11 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input path
s to process : 1
17/05/04 15:23:11 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error checking output specif
ication:
17/05/04 15:23:11 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: java.io.IOException: com.mar
klogic.xcc.exceptions.RequestPermissionException: Authorization failed for user
'admin'.
 [Session: user=admin, cb=content-v11 [ContentSource: user=admin, cb=content-v11
 [provider: address=localhost/127.0.0.1:8907, pool=1/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/8.0-1, Server: XDBC/8.0-3.2]
```

I am facing this problem while loading the data on local MarkLogic setup, I have also setup the path in the options file located. I want to know where I am going wrong. I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

the error suggests that you are using an incorrect username/password combination to connect.

> java.io.IOException: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.RequestPermissionException: Authorization failed for user'admin'.

It'd definitely help if could also share your mlcp options file here so that I can take a look. In that options file for now make sure that:

1. the host & port that you connect to exist and they are correct
2. the username / password combination is also correct

I hope this helps.

Comment: import

-host
localhost

-port
8907

-mode
local

-database
content-v11

-username
admin

-password
admin

-input_file_path
#Set this to wherever you have the training-project-data folder
"C:\Users\as\epmp test\training-sessions\training-1-local-marklogic-setup\training-project-data"

-input_compressed
true

-input_file_type
archive

-thread_count
4                                     this is the options file, have a look tamas

Comment: this does look good to me - so the question is when you connect to 'http://localhost:8001' and you're prompted for a username/password do you enter 'admin/admin' or another combination? If another combination you need to update your options file above and put the right username/password combo.